# App for using Android device as Virtual Instrument host

Tags: android, music, midi

I want to use my mini MIDI controller keyboard with an Android device for performing live. Therefore, I am in search of an app that would recognize usb-midi keyboard and would be easy to switch between instruments in live performance.

May any such virtual instrument host application be suggested that might turn out suitable in this scenario?

N.b. A 2 day google search gives me Caustic 3 as the best option but it seems I won't be able to change instrument patches quick enough as required in live performance as it lacks feature like registration memory (or at least I failed to find one).

Comment: You should add some more details on what features you are looking for besides registration memory.

Comment: @MatthewRead I do not really need other features like, say, styles, rhythms etc. Since you asked, it may be as simple as having say, 8 buttons on the activity, each acting as a registration memory. Before starting a performance I shall be required to load instruments on them (and possibly be able to save presets), and during performance, a simple tapping on one gives me the desired sound. Not a necessity, but it would be nice if I could load more than one instrument on one button for 'dual' or 'split' voices.

Answer (score 0):

You can try remixlive, garageband or lemur.
The first two can be loaded with presets which can be played during live performances.The third is a control surface. If your midi device in any way is not compatiable with any of these, then buy an external soundcard having two(or more) input sources. Then you'll be able to play seamlessly.